# Errors in Google Cast Example 'CastHelloText-Android'

Tags: android, google-cast

I am trying to run [this Google Cast SDK example](https://github.com/googlecast/CastHelloText-android) that is mentioned on the [Cast SDK Android Sender Application Page](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender).

Has anyone tried running this example?

Only changes I made is added my own App Id in res/values/strings.xml and also added the v4 & v7 support library in addition to google-play-services.jar libraries.

Below is the error I see:

[image]

Errors:

```
[2014-02-14 01:08:37 - CastHelloWorld] C:\Users\home\Documents\code\workspace\CastHelloWorld\res\menu\main.xml:20: error: **No resource identifier found for attribute 'actionProviderClass'** in package 'com.example.casthelloworld'

[2014-02-14 01:08:37 - CastHelloWorld] C:\Users\home\Documents\code\workspace\CastHelloWorld\res\menu\main.xml:20: error: **No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction'** in package 'com.example.casthelloworld'
```

These two files are in the res/menu/main.xml - [link to file](https://github.com/googlecast/CastHelloText-android/blob/master/res/menu/main.xml)

Comment: The errors are pasted in the question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you don't need v4 library, please remove that; v7 includes that. Secondly, make sure both appcompat and mediarouter support libraries are added to the dependencies correctly (mediarouter support lib depends on appcompat). Your exception is stating that your dependencies are not set correctly.